# Highcharts:add click event on data label for pie chart

Tags: highcharts

opened a popup by click on a pie-chart slice but not when clicked on a data label.
How to add click event to a data label of a pie-chart?

Answer (score 1):

Update to the last version of Highcharts, using the point select event fires both for the label and the pie slice.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
            point: {
                events: {
                    select: function() {
                        self.yourFunction(this.id);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use html tags and classes in label.formatter, then using jQuery you can add events.

```
dataLabels: {
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function() {
        return '<div class="my-click">' + this.point.name + '</div>';
    }
}
```

And then:

```
$(".my-click").on('click', function(){ /* do somthing */ });
```